# Does Synopsys VCS gives test names that hit the cover?

Tags: system-verilog, test-coverage, synopsys-vcs

Here's the flow of the problem.

- I wrote some general cover.
- There are many tests that may hit a particular cover. Some test will not hit it.
- VCS functional coverage report gives combined hits for a particular cover.
- I want to see what tests hit that particular cover.

Is there any option in VCS?
The simv.vdb data is in xml format and I think it might not be possible to parse that data to obtain tests that hit a cover. Any help appreciated.

Comment: you need to check the `urg` options. It works with the coverage databases.

Comment: Did that. The closest I could find is "-show tests". It just lists out the tests but has no metrics associated with tests individually.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I was looking for, partially.
Following command yields test names for a given metric.

urg –dir [*.vdb] -report [report_name] -show maxtests 10 –show tests –format text/html/both

Haven't explored it much, but it seems it cannot show more than 10 tests in a list, irrespective of the number ahead of maxtests. Second, that list seems to be unsorted, probably -grade can help. Third, only original .vdb file is used, you cant use merged vdb files.